# Product Image not showing on listing page frontend after code migration Magento 2.4.3

Tags: magento2.4, product-images, cache, product-list, full-page-cache

I moved my project to a different directory as the memory is low in the disk, everything is working fine except the product listing page where the images are missing. Showing default image.

[image]

**Wrong hash** - Listing page

```
https://website.com/media/catalog/product/cache/4c6fd00ae61ef17c73c9aecb88f2d715**/2/_/2_207_0269.jpg
```

**Right hash** - Detail page

```
https://website.com/media/catalog/product/cache/91ae248ddb9f31d4e5970a8e8471325f/2/_/2_207_0269.jpg
```

It seems that the cache hash is not correct on the listing page, I tried `sudo php bin/magento catalog:image:resize` but the images are not showing.

How can I Fix this?

Comment: Is that command successful and did you get any error when executing the command = bin/magento catalog:image:resize and please do check the permission settings of the pub/media/catalog and try to access the image from the browser using this path from your magento root directory directly.